# R: loop through data frame extracting subset of data depending on date

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I have a large data frame that consists of data that looks something like this:

```
        date    w    x    y    z    region
1    2012 01    21   43   12    3   NORTH
2    2012 02    32   54   21   16   NORTH
3    2012 03    14   32   65   32   NORTH
4    2012 04    65   33   75   21   NORTH
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
12   2012 12    32   58   53   17   NORTH
13   2012 01    12   47   43   23   SOUTH
14   2012 02    87   43   21   76   SOUTH
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
25   2012 01    12   46   84   29    EAST
26   2012 02    85   29   90   12    EAST
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
:        :      :    :    :    :       :
```

I want to extract section of the data that have the same `date` value, for example to do this just for `2012 01` I would just create a subset of data

```
data_1 <- subset(data, date == "2012 01")
```

and this gives me all the data for `2012 01` but I then go on to apply a function to this data. I would like to be able to apply my function to all possible subsets of my data, so ideally I would be looping through my large data frame and extracting the data for `2012 01, 2012 02, 2012 03, 2012 04...` and applying a function to each of these subsets of data separately.

But I would like to be able to apply this to my data frame even if my data frames length were to change, so it may not always go from `2012 01 - 2012 12`, the range of dates may vary so that sometimes it may be used on data from for example `2011 03 - 2013 01`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

is this what you want ? 
`df_list <- split(data, as.factor(data$date))`

Comment: this is perfect! Such a simple answer for something I thought would be much more complex, thank you

Answer (score 15):

Loop through each unique date and build the subset.

```
uniq <- unique(unlist(data$Date))
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
    data_1 <- subset(data, date == uniq[i])
    #your desired function
}
```

Comment: Will each subset have a unique name? From what I see you're going to end up putting each subset in one dataframe. Thx

Comment: no each loop will just overwrite `data_1` and then the user can apply whatever function to the dataframe and choose themselves where to store  the results.

Comment: @TylerDurden . It looks what I need. What if I want to make subsets based both on region and date? e.g. data_1 <- subset(data, date == "2012 01" & "North")

Comment: @PolarBear thats a new question. Just google it and the answer is straightforward https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=subset+data+r+2+conditions

Answer (score 2):

After sub-setting your dataset by date, imagine that the function you would like to apply to each subset is to find the mean of the column `x`. You could do it this way: (df is your dataframe)

```
 library(plyr)
 ddply(df, .(date), summarize, mean = mean(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your `data.frame` into a `list` of `data.frames` like this:

```
list.of.dfs<-by(data,data$date)
```

Comment: does not seem to work. missing FUN parameter for the by()

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect situation for the `plyr` package:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(my_df, .(date), my_function, extra_arg_1, extra_arg_2)
```

where `my_function` is the function you want to perform on the split data frames, and `extra_arg`s are any extra arguments that need to go to that function.

`ddply` (`d`ata frame -> `d`ata frame) is the form you want if you want your results in a data frame; `dlply` returns a list.